# Scala Dependency Injection using Spring

Tags: java, spring, scala, dependency-injection

I have two modules in a project:

### **Module 1:**

I have a scala class:

**TimeSeries.scala**

```
      trait TimeSeries {
        def series(sourceData: BoundedTimeSeries, destType: Type) : BoundedTimeSeries

        def series(sourceData: BoundedTimeSeries, destType: Type, 
        destDuration: Duration) : BoundedTimeSeries
        }

        object TimeSeries extends TimeSeries {
        def series(sourceData: BoundedTimeSeries, destType: Type) : BoundedTimeSeries = {
        new CalculatedBoundedTimeSeries(sourceData, destType);

        }
         def series(sourceData: BoundedTimeSeries, destType: Type, 
         destDuration: Duration) : BoundedTimeSeries = {
         new ComputedBoundedTimeSeries(sourceData, destType, destDuration);
         }
       }
```

Here is the bean entry in XML file:

```
<bean id="timeSeries" class="com.people.user.booking.TimeSeries" />
```

### Module 2:

In this module, I am using `Autowiring` of scala class `TimeSeries` in below `java` class:

```
class Xyz
{
   @Autowired
   private TimeSeries timeSeries;

   //Some code

   private void callTimeSeries()
   { 
       BoundedTimeSeries series = someMethodToGetSeries();
       Type type = someMethodToGetType();
       timeSeries.series(series, type);
   }

}
```

But I am getting exception like:

```
unsatisfied dependencies: Dependency on
[(objectClass=com.people.user.booking.TimeSeries)] (from bean [&timeSeries])

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: 
Could not instantiate bean class [com.people.user.booking.TimeSeries]
:  Specified class is an interface
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.
SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:67)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.
AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.
instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:990)
... 15 more
```

So Dependency Injection (DI) of TimeSeries scala to XYZ class hasn't happened properly.

I followed the same DI for one java to another java class which is happening fine but DI from Scala to Java is causing such problems.

Is there a different way for Scala Dependency Injection using Spring?

Comment: try it `<bean id="timeSeries" class="com.people.user.booking.TimeSeries$" />`